# Rails protect_from_forgery & ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken issue on multiple domains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudflare

I have ONE app which uses 2 domains.

I noticed that I am always receiving `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` on one domain but never on the other (second has way more traffic - maybe this has something to do with it).

Because of this App is completely useless on first domain - it is no possible to use any form (login/register etc).

The only workaround I found is to add this to ApplicationController:

```
protect_from_forgery if: -> { false }
```

When I added `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` my app crashed on production (but not on development!).

I would like to figure out why are authenticity tokens working on one domain but not on another (they share same resources, db, etc)? Any idea?

Update: I use Cloudflare also.

Comment: Are these two unrelated TL domains -- foo.com and bar.com?  Two peer subdomains -- sub1.bar.com and sub2.bar.com?  Or a sub and a TLD -- sub1.bar.com and bar.com?

Comment: Those are unrelated domains (foo.com & bar.com). I think it must have something to do with cookies - Cloudflare uses HTTP (not HTTPS) protocol in order to reach our server if FLEXIBLE mode is enabled.  This might be causing issues with secure cookies ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured that Cloudflare was the root of the issue: SSL/TLS encryption was set to FLEXIBLE (default settings!) which caused a conflict with cookie policy.

Heroku/Rails returned non-secured cookies (because of non secure request) but because CloudFlare encrypted the content afterwards (SSL), browser ignored `non-secure` cookies.

Solution is to change SSL/TLS encryption from FLEXIBLE to **FULL** on Cloudflare!